# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 when using graphview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, dalvik

My program uses 3 jar files: android-support-v4.jar, jsoup-1.9.1.jar, and graphview-4.1.1.jar. When I had only the first two, my program worked fine. However, when I import the graphview jar, I get the following error: `Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1.` Why is this, and are there any classes/packages in GraphView that are conflicting?